# simpledateformat coverting 24hr time to minutes

Tags: java, android, parsing

I'm wanting to convert 24hr time, e.g. 0748 or 748, into minutes. For some reason it is converting it to only 128 minutes when it should be 468 minutes.

```
double time = 748;
//parse time into SimpleDateFormat to easily extract hours and minutes
Date date_time_to_minutes = new SimpleDateFormat("HHmm").parse(String.valueOf(time));
//hours extracted from time
double extracted_hours = Integer.parseInt(new SimpleDateFormat("HH").format(date_time_to_minutes));
//minutes extracted from time
double extracted_minutes = Integer.parseInt(new SimpleDateFormat("mm").format(date_time_to_minutes));
//converts the extracted hours into minutes and adds it to the extracted minutes
double minutes = extracted_hours * 60 + extracted_minutes;
```

Comment: you're missing 300 min = 5 hours. Take the timezone into account.

Comment: @pyb Incorrect.  If that's true then the output would be 168 (2 hours, 48 minutes).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `HHmm` date format is taking not `7`, but `74` as the number of hours, leaving `8.0` as the minutes.  Inserting this code reveals what is happening.

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
System.out.println(sdf.format(date_time_to_minutes));
```

Output:

```
1970-01-04 02:08:00
```

That is 3 days, 2 hours, and 8 minutes past the epoch (1970-01-01 00:00:00), a.k.a. 74 hours and 8 minutes.

This declaration of `date_time_to_minutes` succeeds, presumably because of the leading "0" I added.

```
Date date_time_to_minutes = new SimpleDateFormat("HHmm").parse("0748");
```

Output:

```
1970-01-01 07:48:00
```

The solution is to ensure that you have a leading zero if the hours value is less than 10.

```
Date date_time_to_minutes = new SimpleDateFormat("HHmm").parse(
  new DecimalFormat("0000").format(time)
);
```